# Monthly regression with a static independent variable

Tags: regression

I am working on my PhD analysis and I am looking to explain monthly anomalous returns (those from momentum or low volatility strategies) using a number of independent variables. The variables range in frequency: monthly, annually and those that do not vary over time. How would I do a regression for this kind of dataset?

As an example: I have monthly momentum returns which I wish to regress against both a static variable (individualism) and an annual data point (equity openness index)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.